# How to append data files in a common (non-user specific) file location on Windows using Java?

Tags: java, export-to-csv, file-permissions

Mostly a conceptual question, though I'll include a little bit of the code I'm using. I have a program that is almost ready to be built, but I'm trying to set up for distro by saving its outputs to a common use folder (e.g. C-drive or Program Files) rather than my user specific IDE folder I have done my testing in. When I launch my program from my IDE directory (e.g. C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\etc) the program appends the CSV files without issue. However, when I move the desired outputs to C:\data, the CSV's aren't appended. The program runs without any errors and reads the file contents properly, but it seems its appendages aren't saved.

My best guess is this is a file permissions issue, so I wrote a class to try to handle this that is called before the file is appended. Again, it runs, but doesn't seem to allow for the modifications to save...

How do I make it so these CSV files can be regularly appended without needing to know the name of the user profile? I've tried some command line permissions changes to grant full access to the directory, but Java still seems like it can't save the appendages. I'll include the class I have to change the file permissions:

```
public class SetPermissions {

public File ChangePermissions(File f) {
    boolean exists = f.exists();
    if(exists == true) {
        f.setExecutable(true);
        f.setWritable(true);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("File not found...");
    }
    return f;
}
}
```

*EDIT: To add further clarification, what I need is a way for the data file to be created and have regular appendages saved to it, and for that location to be generic enough for any user account (and eventually any platform) to utilize it.

Comment: On every platform, the user is generally somewhat restricted on what they can write - except in their home folder. You can't randomly change file permissions. And you can't change file permissions if the user can't do it. So please clarify exactly what you want to do (not how you intend to do it). As far as I can tell, you really just want `String home = System.getProperty("user.home");` and then to pick file locations relative to that.

Comment: I'll clarify this here and in an edit. I really just need a way for the data file to be created and appended by any user (any admin) when I distribute the software. This program makes ongoing edits, so it needs to be able to regularly save changes when it automatically pulls the data. I'd prefer if the path is as similar as possible too so I can include it in the readme file. I will look into your suggestion though, thank you

Comment: I hope you don't have quotas on the hard drive.